# How can docker containers reliably indicate that they're not just running, but ready?

Tags: docker

I have a Docker container which runs a small TCP server providing a microservice.

Once the containerized process starts, it takes a few milliseconds for the process to begin listening on its ports. If I try to connect before then, any client's connection will die with `connection refused`.

Busy-waiting for the container's status to change to `running` is not enough to prevent this, because it takes time after the process has started for the service to be brought up.

**What is a good/conventional way for a container process to indicate to the host that it is truly ready for use?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Polling the service *is* the conventional approach.  Pay no attention to what Docker is saying; try to make the connection, and if you do get a connection-refused error, retry until either it succeeds or you've waited too long.

Most containers will only actually begin listening on their TCP port only when they're actually ready to accept traffic.  Clients generally deal with this by polling the socket, often using a purpose-built tool like [wait-for-it](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it).  A very reasonable alternate approach is for a client to try to connect on initial startup, crash if that connection fails, and let the orchestrator restart the pod (even as little as [`docker run --restart on-failure`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#restart-policies---restart) is enough to make this work).

Since containers are isolated from their host system, there simply isn't another path where a container can advertise "I'm ready!".  If a container, say, created a file to advertise readiness, then it would require some shared storage with the host system to be able to create the file, and the orchestrator (*e.g.*, Docker Compose) would need to be aware of this.  That's not a standard part of any of the usual orchestrators.

The other important aspect to the polling approach is that neither the problem nor the solution are specific to Docker.  If you just run `service mysql start` on an Ubuntu host with no Docker involved, it will still take a minute or so to come up, and the same polling approach will work.  If the database is somewhere on a different host, or on a cloud provider, you don't have a shared filesystem but again you can poll it until it's ready.  Tools like [Consul](https://consul.io/) can build up a service catalog based on polling known services.  [@DavidSzalai's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58701291/10008173) mentions Kubernetes health checks, which again have a similar approach (and "try to connect, or crash" is definitely the normal way to manage Kubernetes-hosted clients).

Comment: This is what I ended up using— thankfully I have control over the connection-making code, so I can catch the connection error and retry without killing the process. In this case it is more performant than long-delay polls or repeated process starts, and more efficient that healthchecks running in a tight loop for the life of the container. I do still have to wait for the container to flip to 'running' before I can obtain the port mappings and attempt to connect, however, so I can't quite "ignore what docker is saying". :) This is far from elegant, but as good as Docker permits.

Answer (score 1):

Id depends on how/where you run your containers. There is a `HEALTHCHECK` command for Dockerfiles and Docker Compose/Swarm: https://blog.sixeyed.com/docker-healthchecks-why-not-to-use-curl-or-iwr/.

```
HEALTHCHECK --interval=5s --timeout=3s CMD curl --fail http://localhost:8091/pools || exit
```

It is a simple script that returns an error if the container is not ready.

In Kubernetes, PODs can define health checks and readiness checks too: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    test: liveness
  name: liveness-exec
spec:
  containers:
  - name: liveness
    image: k8s.gcr.io/busybox
    args:
    - /bin/sh
    - -c
    - touch /tmp/healthy; sleep 30; rm -rf /tmp/healthy; sleep 600
    livenessProbe:
      exec:
        command:
        - cat
        - /tmp/healthy
      initialDelaySeconds: 5
      periodSeconds: 5
```

They both look the same, but have a bit difference: if a container is not healthy, it will be restarted, while readiness check failures will not restart containers. Checks are marked as "failed" if they failed a predefined number of times (it is configurable).

Health-checks in Dockerfile [is not supported in K8s](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/50796), so you should use the Kubernetes ones if you deploy there.

Comment: This is good info, but (1) I'm not running Kubernetes, and (2) multiple-second polling times are much too long for my application. The ideal solution would be one where the container could perform some notification (creating/writing to a file, sending a signal, etc.) as soon as it knows it's up.

Comment: ...though if HEALTHCHECK (or an equivalent) allowed for different polling periods during and after the startup period (e.g. 0.1s during startup, 60s after), that would probably do the job.

Comment: If you are looking for a standard way, you should use a health-check with the configuration that fits you. E.g. a 1-second interval is pretty good for any service to start. I would go this way as it will be the best in the long term.

Comment: Unfortunately I think there is no different config for startup and running phases :(